# Create Web Service in ZK

Tags: zk

I want to create an web service, I am quiet familiar with zk. Can I create web service in ZK?
My web service should be able to send response in the form of XML/JSON objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK framework basically concentrates on UI. I donnot think it can be used to implement web services even if u can it won't be a good Idea to when u have other good frameowrks like Play!.